# SELECT COUNT Per Date and Type SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an SQL Query below.

```
SELECT sched_date, sched_name, employee_name from tbl_schedule
```

It returns this result:

```
    sched_date    sched_name              employee_name

    2017-04-01    09:00 AM - 06:00 PM     M.G.Cave
    2017-04-01    09:00 AM - 06:00 PM     L.C.Manalo
    2017-04-01    11:00 AM - 8:00 PM      R.M.Jakosalem
    2017-04-01    11:00 AM - 8:00 PM      S.D.Dela Cruz
    2017-04-02    Rest Day                M.G.Cave
    2017-04-02    Rest Day                L.C.Manalo
    2017-04-02    Rest Day                R.M.Jakosalem
    2017-04-02    Rest Day                S.D.Dela Cruz
```

I want the employees to be counted per date and per schedule. My desired result is:

```
    2017-04-01    09:00 AM - 06:00 PM     2 employees
    2017-04-01    11:00 AM - 8:00 PM      2 employees
    2017-04-02    Rest Day                4 employees
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, I tried several queries but it gives me an error so I didn't mind including it into this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GROUP BY` on the `sched_date`, `sched_name` and a `COUNT(*)` will get you your desired result:

```
SELECT 
   sched_date, 
   sched_name, 
   COUNT(*) AS employees 
from 
   tbl_schedule
GROUP BY 
   sched_date, 
   sched_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below query :

```
 SELECT *
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT sched_date, sched_name, COUNT(*) AS employees 
    FROM tbl_schedule
    GROUP BY sched_date,sched_name
 ) A
```